# how to print from json file using python

Tags: python, json

I have a json file url - http://****

and want to print ticket price and id from it. I am stuck & do not know how to proceed.

The code I have is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json
from pprint import pprint
json_data=open('./test.json')
data= json.load(json_data)
pprint(data)
json_data.close()
```

With the above code , i am getting output as

```
 [{u'currency': u'USD',
 u'exchange': u'USNASD',
 u'id': u'CA98420N1050',
 u'name': u'Xenon Pharmaceuticals Inc',
 u'price': 7.85,
 u'ticker': u'XENE'},
 {u'currency': u'EUR',
 u'exchange': u'XDUB',
 u'id': u'IE0003295239',
 u'name': u'FYFFES PLC',
 u'price': 1.47}]
```

I dont kow why I am getting U as output and I know want ticker, id and price from this file. Help!

Comment: The "u"s are normal. That's how Python lets you know they're Unicode strings. If you really don't like them, you can upgrade to Python 3.X and they'll go away :-)

Comment: @ajs it looks like you're outsourcing answering an interview question: `This should be treated as confidential and not posted publicly. i.e. don't post this on Stack Overflow or share`

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

with open("marketdata.json") as fd:
    data = json.load(fd)

for i in data:
    print("{ticker}|{id}|{price}".format(**i))
```

Learn more about `.format()` in this [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings):

Comment: {ubuntu@ubuntu:~/json$ cat github.py 
#!/usr/bin/python
import json
with open("test.json") as fd:
 data = json.load(fd)
for i in data:
 print("{ticker}|{id}|{price}".format(**i))
}

while running the code, getting following error --- Is it due to wrong formatting command ? 
    {
    ubuntu@ubuntu:~/json$ python github.py 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "github.py", line 9, in <module>
    print("{ticker}|{id}|{price}".format(**i))
    TypeError: format() argument after ** must be a mapping, not unicode
}

Comment: This gives me output as
{TSTIF|CA8730151013|1.866
XENE|CA98420N1050|7.85
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ateet1.py", line 6, in <module>
    print("{ticker}|{id}|{price}".format(**i))
KeyError: 'ticker'
}
i need output in json format

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the JSON object:

```
import json

def parseJSON(jsonObj):
    parsed_json = json.load(jsonObj)
    return parsed_json

parsedJson = parseJson(<your_json_obj>)+
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use:

```
data = json.loads(json_data)
print(json.dumps(data,indent=4,sort_keys=True))
```

This will give you the output in indented format.